# SQL: Convert multiple columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a table in below format
[image]
I need to convert it to this format

[image]

SO basically i am looking to convert multiple columns to rows. Can some one help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: Please use plain text format for sample data, instead of images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try

```
select *
  from yourTable
  unpivot (
    Value
    for NewCol in (Value1, Value2, Value3,Value4, Value5)
  ) up
```

Comment: Thanks nazark, this works for me. appreciate the help here.

Answer (score 3):

Converting columns to rows is called unpivoting.  Converting rows to columns is pivoting.

One approach to unpivoting data is to combine the [apply operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) with a [table value constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx).

This example uses a [common table expression (CTE)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175972.aspx) to return 3 sample records.

```
Id  ColumnOne   ColumnTwo   ColumnThree
1   a           b           c
2   d           e           f
3   g           h           i
```

**Example**

```
-- Unpivoting with apply and VALUES.        
WITH SampleData AS
    (
        /* This CTE returns 3 sample records.
         */             
        SELECT
            cte.*
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1, 'a', 'b', 'c'),
                    (2, 'd', 'e', 'f'),
                    (3, 'g', 'h', 'i')
            ) AS cte(Id, ColumnOne, ColumnTwo, ColumnThree)
    )
SELECT
    sd.Id,
    ca.*
FROM
    SampleData AS sd
        CROSS APPLY
            (
                VALUES
                    (ColumnOne),
                    (ColumnTwo),
                    (ColumnThree)
            ) AS ca (ColumnFour)
;
```

The returned output looks like this:

```
Id  ColumnFour
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   d
2   e
2   f
3   g
3   h
3   i
```

Personally I prefer @nazark's approach.  Using the [UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) operator helps others to follow the intention of your code.  If that answer helped you please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor for his/her efforts and helps other people with the same problem to find a working answer.

Comment: Thanks for explaining all that.. nazark's response helped me get the required results